# Как получить все обработчики, которые есть у определённого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlers

Можно ли получить все обработчики, которые есть у определённого элемента?
Видел такой способ: `$._data(element, 'events');`, но он не всегда работает: в коде ниже показывается только обработчик mousemove

```js
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
$('img').on('mousemove', function() {
  console.log('mousemove');
});

function showHandlers(element) {
  console.log($._data(element, 'events'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
<input type="button" value="Show handlers" onclick="showHandlers($('img')[0])">
```

Как получить все обработчики?

Answer (score 3):

Код `showHandlers` выдает только один обработчик, потому что только один обработчик повешен на `img`. `$(document).on('click', ...` повешен на `document`. Если нужно достать такие обработчики, необходимо пройтись по всем родителям элемента, на самый верх, до `document`.